# Confusion over Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm reading Freund's statistics book and he says the following:

"Just as the hypergeometric distribution takes the place of the binomial distribution for sampling without replacement, there also exists a multivariate distribution analogous to the multinomial distribution that applies to sampling without replacement."

So this makes me think the multinomial distribution is for situations *with* replacement.  But he gives this example which seems to indicate otherwise:

"A city has 3 newspapers: A, B, and C.  A has 50% of readers in the city, B has 30%, C has 20%.  Find probability that, among 8 randomly chosen readers, 5 will read A, 2 will read B, and 1 will read C?  (Assume that no one reads more than one newspaper)."

How is this a situation *with* replacement?  Seems like once I get the probability that 5 read A, this changes my probabilities for 2 reading B and 1 reading C.  But in a situation *with* replacement, these probabilities shouldn't change.

Where am I going wrong?

Any clarification would be awesome!

Thanks,
Mariogs

Answer (score 1):

You're right in saying it is really sampling without replacement. But the population in question, readers in a particular city, is very large, and for large populations sampling with replacement is a very good approximation for a sampling-without-replacement scenario such as this, and is usually easier to calculate.

It's also a sensible approach because the exact numbers aren't known anyway: that is, the exact numbers of readers for A, B and C.